# While building items.xml, it is throwing namespace error

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

So I have created enumtype, relation type and while trying to build it is throwing the below mentioned error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot merge namespace ((trainingcore)) into (()) due to duplicate type code 'creditcardtype' : CreditCardType::((trainingcore))::YEnumType[trainingcore-items.xml:31(EnumTypeTagListener)]<>CreditCardType::((core))::YEnumType[payment-items.xml:22(EnumTypeTagListener)]
>
> at de.hybris.bootstrap.typesystem.YNamespace.mergeNamespace(YNamespace.java:195)

I have already commented out the yaccelerator extensions in the extensionsinfo file. But it still throws this error. Could anyone help me out in this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to show some code to make it easier to see the issue causing the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you add the content of your items.xml? most likely you are creating an enum that already exists. for that you need to add generate=false autocreate=false to append the options to the existing enum object